# Did Mathematica make a mistake or was it me?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, piecewise

I'm having a little trouble with Mathematica. There are two expressions that should be equal over a given region. Each of which consists of three terms that should be equal individually:

term1 of equation1 = term1 of equation2

term2 of equation1 = term2 of equation2

term3 of equation1 = term3 of equation2

That's also what I get. Using FullSimplify on the three equations above returns true three times. However, when I compare the equation using FullSimplify, so FullSimplify[equation1==equation2] I don't get a true statement.

So either I'm having a mistake in my code or mathematical is making a mistake.

Would be very nice if someone could help. Thank's in advance

Luca

here I add the code as a link to the wolfram cloud:

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/3fd69044-cb78-4328-9779-1e8ea6c231f9

The first four cells just define the functions.
The fifth cell first checks equation1==equation2 and then the three terms individually

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates to the specifics of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your function definitions

```
expr1 = Dm*
    D[W1sidemesasfixed[x], {x, 
      2}] + (2*mstatsidemesas[x]*cstatsidemesas[x] - k)*
    W1sidemesasfixed[
     x] - (2/R0)*(2*mstatsidemesas[x]*cstatsidemesas[x] - k)*
    W2sidemesasfixed[x];

expr2 = Dm*
    D[((W1basis[-(x - (α*L - Lminus))] /. C1 -> 0) /. 
       C3 -> 0), {x, 
      2}] + (2*(mbasis[-(x - (α*L - 
              Lminus))])*(cbasis[-(x - (α*L - Lminus))]) - 
      k)*((W1basis[-(x - (α*L - Lminus))] /. C1 -> 0) /. 
      C3 -> 0) - (2/
      R0)*(2*(mbasis[-(x - (α*L - 
              Lminus))])*(cbasis[-(x - (α*L - Lminus))]) - 
      k)*((W2basis[-(x - (α*L - Lminus))] /. C1 -> 0) /. 
      C3 -> 0);
```

Comparing term-by-term

```
FullSimplify[Thread[(List @@ expr1) == (List @@ expr2)], 
 x < α*L]

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Comparing full expressions

```
Assuming[x < α*L, 
 expr1 == expr2 // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I'm still confused though. When I implement it your way and write: Assuming[x < α*L, 
 expr1 == expr2 // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify] I get the desired "true". But when I write FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2, x < α*L] it doesn't work. Could you please explain why these expressions are apparently not the same?

Comment: Presumably, `FullSimplify` times out and stops trying to simplify before it tries using `PiecewiseExpand` (assuming that it ever tries using `PiecewiseExpand`). Directly invoking `PiecewiseExpand` ensures that it is used. Alternatively, add `PiecewiseExpand` to the `TransformationFunctions` option: `Assuming[x < α*L, expr1 == expr2 // FullSimplify[#, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PiecewiseExpand}]&]`

Comment: Reminds me why I dislike computers...Thank you Bob Hanlon. That was really helpful